# Restoring a Snow Leopard time capsule using Leopard DVD boot? possible?

Tags: macos

So I have a time capsule of a few machines.
The one i did last (Snow Leopard) doesn't seem to be showing in the list.
I don't have a snow leopard DVD boot handy only Leopard.
Is this why this isn't in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I'm afraid this is the case. You will need to find a Snow Leopard DVD or Lion recovery HD/USB to restore your files.

Since this DVD used to come with all Macs, you should be able to find a friend who has one. Otherwise, try the Apple store or AppleCare to order a replacement Snow Leopard DVD.

Comment: Install DVDs that come with machines are machine-specific, down to the build. Make sure that if you borrow a DVD from another machine that it's identical to yours.